# Attempted to register a view with an id already in use

Tags: ember.js

Since this [commit](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/04df12c25fe3c9afb21b5e055e74d58ce3339f2f) we can't registrer a view with an ID twice. This seems logical. However I got an issue.

**Router**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('contact', { path: '/contacts/:contact_id' });
});

App.ContactShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
```

**View**

```
App.ContactShowView = Em.View.extend({
   elementId: "page-show-contact"
});
```

Consider that I'm already on the route **App.ContactShowRoute**. I would like to **transitionTo()** the same route but with a different context.

I expected emberjs to destroy the view and then create it again, but I got the following error:

```js
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: page-show-contact
```

I don't want to instantiate a view with the same ID twice. I just want ember to destroy the actual one and then create a new one.

Comment: I guess Ember trys to instantiate the new View, when the old View is still in the DOM and still registered with Ember. Now your new new View gets created and the elementId is assigned. At this moment you got 2 View objects with the same id, but only one is in the DOM. Why do you need to define the elementId yourself? I think there is a fast workaround.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug in the current version. Maybe you should open a ticket.
Until this is fixed, this might help:

```
App.ContactShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

   renderTemplate : function(controller, model) {
    if(this.lastRenderedTemplate == this.routeName) 
       return; 
    return this._super();
   }
});
```

Comment: What is lastRenderedTemplate ? is it part of API ?